# Customize web form script generation

Tags: webforms, content-security-policy

Ok, yes, it's 2020 but don't laugh.  I'm trying update some ASP.NET web forms.  My goal is to lock them down, making them more secure by applying a more restrictive Content Security Policy (CSP).  To that end, I'm using a nonce, rather than allowing `unsafe-inline` for scripting.

For "simple" web forms, it's working fine. However, I hit a problem whenever there's an ASP control that results in a post back.  When I look in the page source, I see stuff like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

and

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function previewFile() {
        var preview = document.querySelector('#Body_Main_LogoImage');
        var file = document.querySelector('#Body_Main_logoUpload').files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {
            preview.src = reader.result;
        }

        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            preview.src = "";
        }
    }
</script>
```

This code is generated by some of the MS web form code, I believe.  The problem is  that neither of these script elements have a nonce, which I'd like to supply, so it is in violation of my CSP (which does not include `unsafe-inline`).  Is there anything I can override to customize this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the offending code is defined in a private method (e.g. `RenderPostBackScript`) inside the `Page` class, which in turn is called by internal methods.  So, overriding it the normal way isn't an option unless I replace a large bunch of code.  As an alternative, I overrode `CreateHtmlTextWriter` in my page:

```cs
protected override System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter CreateHtmlTextWriter(TextWriter tw)
{
    return new HtmlTextWriter(tw, this);
}
```

and then in my `HtmlWriter` class, I do this:

```cs
public override void Write(string s)
{
    if (s != null && s.IndexOf("<script") > -1 && s.IndexOf("nonce") == -1 && s.IndexOf("src") == -1)
    {
        s = s.Replace("<script", "<script nonce=\"" + this._page.GetNonce() + "\"");
    }
    base.Write(s);
}
```

I used a similar approach in my `HtmlTextWriter` for `AddAttribute` to avoid inline `javascript:` inside `href`, which would required `unsafe-inline` for `script-src` (and preclude the use of a nonce).

```cs
public override void AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute key, string value)
{
    if (key == HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href && value != null && value.IndexOf("javascript:") > -1)
    {
        base.AddAttribute(key, "#");
        var newScript = value.Replace("javascript:", "");
        newScript += "; return false;";
        base.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Onclick, newScript);
    }
    else
    {
        base.AddAttribute(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: How / Where did you add the nonce back to the request header in your web-forms page? Did you also encounter issues with `WebResource.axd` files that would require unsafe-eval?

Comment: @rm-code, I added the nonce back in the script tag in the override of the Write method of the the HtmlWriter class. Please see answer above.  I didn't run into any issues with WebResource.axd (guess I got lucky)

Comment: I must be being thick, how did you define _page to access the GetNonce method? I'm using VB.Net and it's not as forgiving as C#. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could override `__DoPostBack` and use your own function instead.

```
var __original= __doPostBack;
__doPostBack = myFunction();
```

some more ideas over here:
[How to intercept any postback in a page? - ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234542/how-to-intercept-any-postback-in-a-page-asp-net)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the link.  The RegisterOnSubmitStatement idea looks interesting.  But I came up with another solution, which I'll share as an answer

Comment: @Notre Could you please share the solution or approach you took?

Comment: @PramilGawande, I used the approach I described in the first answer

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the dev tools in Chrome, you'll likely see a message like

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: `"script-src 'self'`. Either the `'unsafe-inline'` keyword, a hash (`'sha256-2NqnatcPqy5jjBXalTpZyJMO/0fUaYUb3ePlviUP4II='`), or a nonce (`'nonce-...'`) is required to enable inline execution.

If you look carefully at that message, it's telling you what the hash would be: `sha256-2NqnatcPqy5jjBXalTpZyJMO/0fUaYUb3ePlviUP4II=`

So if you don't want to go the nonce route, you can instead go the hash route and add

```bash
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'sha256-2NqnatcPqy5jjBXalTpZyJMO/0fUaYUb3ePlviUP4II=' 'unsafe-eval';
```

You may have to add `unsafe-eval` in some cases as well for this to work.