# SignalR Content-Security-Policy issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, signalr, content-security-policy

I'm trying to implement .NET SignalR (v2.4.0) to some of our project but,
SignalR `$.connection.hub.start` method give CSP error, we don't want to use **'unsafe-inline'** CSP directive for scripts because of security conserns

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src

Is there any method or configuration to solve this problem?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement CORS depending on where you are loading resources from.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain

Comment: Hi, its not about CORS, i have already CORS implemented i can successfully request to server

Comment: Cool. I saw the error with starting the connection and thought it might be that.

Answer (score 0):

The violation message in the Chrome console:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
 Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
```

means you have inline scripts kind of `<script>...</script>` on the page.

You can allow such scripts by using `'nonce-value'` or `'hash-value'` tokens. Alternatively you can move this script to external file, in this case it falls under `script-src 'self'` permission.

Comment: Hi, i don't have any inline scripts in my application, signalr start response has inline script and i cant add nonce or hash because signalr generates it automaticly

Comment: May be you can override `HtmlTextWriter()` or `__doPostBack()` methods to intercept HTML and add 'nonce' on the fly, pls see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722871/customize-web-form-script-generation/62802596#62802596).